# how to set image position in post for wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am using css for wordpress to set image position in post?

```
single.php    
<?php if(have_posts()) : ?><?php while(have_posts()) : the_post();  ?>  
     <div align="center"><h6><?php the_title();?></h6></div>
         <div class="isi">  

    <?php the_content();?>

         </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else : ?>


    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?> " <?php post_class(); ?>
    <h2><?php _e('Not Found'); ?></h2>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>


style.css
.isi img{float:left; }
```

the view that i want

```
image ---------
---------------
---------------
----------image
---------------
```

is there any idea for solve my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add an image to a WordPress page or post, it asks you if you want to align it left, middle or right. Just select one of these options before you insert it into post.

If you have built a custom theme, remember to add this to your CSS

```
.alignleft{float: left;}

.alignright{float: right;}
```

Answer (score 1):

pretty vague and without seeing the page, even vaguer, but here goes: add class of floatleft to your first image and floatright to your second. look here: http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/f6mJp/

Comment: no, my bos want user doesn't need to code anything so i need css like above to solve my problem. thanks for the answer

Comment: i'm confused...the solution i provided is the exact same thing @toby_lh gave...albeit i like his explanation better, it's not like you gave much to go on